# How to create a file on the Client Drive with PHP

Tags: php

I want code that upload on the host whenever website is load then one file create on client drive c:\ , i put buton code  on the localhost is true but when i put this code on the host creat file on public_html but i want create file on client C:\ Drive similar a Virus

Comment: You need to ask the user to download it (as with usual downloads via PHP), no way around.

Comment: yes, you must have permissions of user, else it will be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The user needs to download it manually

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server, not the client machine. In other words PHP can never affect the client machine.